# Catch Outlook events when attaching/sending a file from another application

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, office-interop, outlook-addin

I'm trying to create an add-in for Outlook 2007/2010 to **modify recipients** of newly created email messages.  Everything works fine if the user creates a new email message inside Outlook (*I'm using the `Inspectors.NewInspector` event*).  But if the user uses another application (*MS Word or Adobe Acrobat for example*) to try to email an attachment, the `NewInspector` event isn't fired when the compose email window is displayed.  Is there a straightforward approach to catching an event that is raised in a situation like this?

I've tried using the `Application.ItemLoad` event, but I can't access any methods or properties after I successfully cast it to an `Outlook.MailItem` (*I get an error stating `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The item’s properties and methods cannot be used inside this event procedure`*).  I'm using C# in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Outlook.exe` process is not running then the `NewInspector` won't fire since `ThisAddIn_Startup` is not called except when the user opens up Outlook directly.

Since Outlook is not already running when the external application opens the new `Inspector` window - you would have to manually call `ThisAddIn_Startup` yourself or attach any custom events that need to fire when the `Inspector` ribbon is loaded. The best place to do this is by [handling `CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject` or `RequestService` methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608601.aspx).

```cs
protected override object RequestService(Guid serviceGuid)
{
    if (serviceGuid == typeof(Office.IRibbonExtensibility).GUID)
       this.ThisAddIn_Startup(this, null);

    return base.RequestService(serviceGuid);
}
```

The only caveat with this is that you need to support method re-entry with `ThisAddIn_Startup` since the Ribbon and Outlook can both call the startup routine now. You will need to safely administer a lock to ensure you don't keep calling your `Init`  (*`ThisAddIn_Startup`*) routine more than once.